# Entity Framework Core HasOne and WithMany doesn’t exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Why could I haven’t `HasOne()` and `WithMany()` parameters in `modelBiulder.Entity<T>` method?

Answer (score 3):

To configure a relationship using the Fluent API in Entity Framework Core, you start by identifying the navigation properties that make up the relationship. `HasOne` or `HasMany` identifies the navigation property on the entity type you are beginning the configuration on. You then chain a call to `WithOne` or `WithMany` to identify the inverse navigation. `HasOne/WithOne` are used for reference navigation properties and `HasMany/WithMany` are used for collection navigation properties.

Please see the [Microsoft documentation with example.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

**Example:**

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

class ApplicatioinDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Blog)
            .WithMany(b => b.Posts);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to add that in your example the last instruction is redundant (.HasOne.WithMany) because your example follows the EF Core conventions. You only need that when you don't follow the conventions. For instance, if your primary keys were not called PostId / BlogId.